# is there any solution for Magento installing error for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, magento

As a biginner I tried to instrall Magento.its showing error when instralling. first I explian my status.

php version : PHP 8.2.12
XAMP : V3.3.0
Apache/2.4.58
phpMyAdmin : 5.2.1
Composer version 2.6.6 2023-12-08 18:32:26
Elasticsearch: 8.11.3
Magento : 2.4.6

first I download and install Composer.then Elasticsearch. security is enable when I try to open localhost:9200, it ask password. I already reset password using "elasticsearch-reset-password.bat".

step 1:
composer.phar global config http-basic.repo.magento.com abeffa5b80eb43d4ba2a78d0aa4e3696 635c95a490c8682aa942f4cb469e898a

step 2:
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition

step3:
create database name : m246

step4:
Enable elasticsearch opening this file :
c:/xampp/htdocs/elasticsearch-7.17.0/bin/elasticsearch.bat

Step5:
Install Magento command:-

php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/m246/pub --db-host=localhost --db-name=m246 --db-user=root --db-password= --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=admin@admin.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --backend-frontname=admin --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=localhost --elasticsearch-port=9200

here is coming error
like this
"In SearchConfig.php line 81:

Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. Unknown 401 error from Elasticsearch null"

then I try to run this code
"curl localhost:9200/_cat/health"
answer is :

**{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/_cat/health]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8"","ApiKey"]}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/_cat/health]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8"","ApiKey"]}},"status":401}**

help me to troubleshoot this

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [Docker-Magento](https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento) . Using this you can easily install magento 2 with all dependencies. But it use **docker** and make our process easier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need put the credentials with the params

```
--elasticsearch-enable-auth=ELASTICSEARCH-ENABLE-AUTH
--elasticsearch-username=ELASTICSEARCH-USERNAME
--elasticsearch-password=ELASTICSEARCH-PASSWORD
```

[see more in this link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Elasticsearch-is-the-default-catalog-search-engine-in-Magento-2/ba-p/447968)